# DJ Thief We Have To Stop

Tags: controls

We have a thief in Virginia who is and has been stealing people's service for at least two years and running a group with at least 5 drones.
He has also hacked them out and burnt holes in old women among chasing them with it in cars and more as a Santanic group. 
We need to find this person as he is cause of giving us a bad name.
Uses Verizon DLINK2500 TP2500. , 69.78.96.14. Also 174.255.207.224. 890L64b2 on Verizon.  Mac 38-46-08-1c-63-ae. Goes by Serialconsole1 or Shaezche among others.
He has ask questions on every form he can. 
Please if you find him STOP HIM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its nonsense

Comment: You can call it anything you like but the fact remains that people like these is why good individuals can not do half of what ee should.

Comment: Regardless, this is NOT the forum you need to be contacting.